# application installation in program files

Tags: c#, wpf, installation

I'm building an installer for my application and I'm curious about choosing my installation path.

If I were to write in Program Files, I'd have to build the installer application with administrator requirement manifest. 
I'm afraid of doing that because it might throw off potential customers.

The main application (not the installer, these are 2 separate projects in a solution) will have update feature; and that in this case will, as well, require elevation to write to the installation folder, and if I were to build the main application like that, it would mean all users would be forced to run the app as Administrator or at very least, before every run of the application they would have UAC on their screen which is something I personally hate seeing and I'm sure others are too.

Yet, on the other hand I don't want to install to AppData/Local since it's not really professional even though there is full write permission there.

What are your suggestions regarding how I should approach this?

Would it be a good idea to make an Updater project that will require elevation and will programmatically launch from main application?

Comment: Just interesting, why not to use Inno Setup or similar?

Comment: @Spawn I'm developer in learning, I'm trying to write as much as original code as I can to get a good grip of everything. That's mainly why I decided to build my own installer + there are some app specific detail that I don't think other installers can incoprorate (account registration that's connected to my web domain through PHP API I wrote, for example).